# Sitecore powershell 100 item limit

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I have a requirement to replace a load (2000+) images within the Sitecore media library with optimised images with the same name. I need to keep the original GUIDS so that all images are still linked.

So I basically need to replace the image blob data and size data. I have written a powershell script to do this however I have found it consistently will all process 100 items. I can not see any reason for this, it could just be my script is rubbish as i haven't used powershell much before.

```
$CurrentImages = Get-Item  -Path master: -Query '/sitecore/media library/Images/Products//*[@@TemplateName="Jpeg"]';


$NewImages = Get-Item  -Path master: -Query '/sitecore/media library/NewImages//*[@@TemplateName="Jpeg"]';

Write-Host $NewImages.Count;


$CurrentImages|foreach{ $Current = $_;  $NewImages|foreach{ $New = $_; if($New.DisplayName -eq $Current.DisplayName){ Write-Host $Current.DisplayName; $Current.Blob = $New.Blob; $Current.Size = $New.Size; $New | Remove-Item}}};
```

Im using the sitecore powershell extention if that also helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limit is actually imposed on the query mechanism by the CMS in `Sitecore.config`. You can find the following line, and change it to up the limit:

`<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />`

However I would suggest that in case of larger searches you might want to use the `Find-Item` cmdlet that utilizes the Sitecore Content Search infrastructure.

You can find more different strategies to locate content in [the Gist I've put together some time ago with performance analysis](https://gist.github.com/AdamNaj/273458beb3f2b179a0b6).

In case of `Find-Item` however you will want to pipe your search results into `Initialize-Item` to turn the Search result items into full sitecore items.

**Edit**: As learned on the Slack schannel (Thanks Kamruz Jaman!)
This limit is further augmented in Sitecore 8.1 in `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config` to 260, but clearly in your case the first limit is still the case.

```
<setting name="Query.MaxItems">
    <patch:attribute name="value">260</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

Comment: oh ok I wouldn't have thought to look in Sitecore.config i've been look through all the powershell config. thank you very much